# Loop Through Collection of XML Records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, loops

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<process xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <return>
    <approved>
      <callbackTable>
        <tableRow max="100" value="10" selectedRow="true" maxRow="112.0">
          <tableCell term="72" selectedCell="false" maxCell="73">
            <number>21.7</number>
          </tableCell>
          <tableCell term="74" selectedCell="true" maxCell="75">
            <number>21.7</number>
          </tableCell>
        </tableRow>
        <tableRow max="200" value="15" selectedRow="false" maxRow="113.0">
          <tableCell term="76" selectedCell="false" maxCell="77">
            <number>14.5</number>
          </tableCell>
          <tableCell term="78" selectedCell="false" maxCell="79">
            <number>22.5</number>
          </tableCell>
        </tableRow>
        <tableRow max="300" value="20" selectedRow="false" maxRow="114.0">
          <tableCell term="80" selectedCell="false" maxCell="81">
            <number>14.6</number>
          </tableCell>
          <tableCell term="82" selectedCell="false" maxCell="83">
            <number>15.7</number>
          </tableCell>
        </tableRow>
      </callbackTable>
    </approved>
  </return>
</process>
```

I need to be able to loop through the **callbackTable** entries and add them to a table named **Options**.

Here is what I need the data to ultimately look like in the **Options** table.

| Id | Max | Value | SelectedRow | MaxRow | Term | SelectedCell | MaxCell | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | true | 112.0 | 72 | false | 73 | 21.7 |
| 2 | 100 | 10 | true | 112.0 | 74 | true | 75 | 21.7 |
| 3 | 200 | 15 | false | 113.0 | 76 | false | 77 | 14.5 |
| 4 | 200 | 15 | false | 113.0 | 78 | false | 79 | 22.5 |
| 5 | 300 | 20 | false | 114.0 | 80 | false | 81 | 14.6 |
| 6 | 300 | 20 | false | 114.0 | 82 | false | 83 | 15.7 |

(Note that the Id column is an identity key and does not need to be populated)

The tricky part is that I don't know exactly how many rows or how many cells are in the callbackTable collection so I will need to loop through the results and insert based on the number of items in the collection.

I could really use some help as I'm not entirely sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't need to loop... there is xml support in SQL Server which should allow you to pull that as a query. I'm not familiar with it, but I suggest checking the SQL Server XML docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the encoding in the XML processing instruction to `utf-16` or omit it, try the set-based query below. Note the `Id` column of the target table is omitted from the column list so that SQL Server will assign the `IDENTITY` value.

```
DECLARE @xml xml =
<process xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <return>
    <approved>
      <callbackTable>
        <tableRow max="100" value="10" selectedRow="true" maxRow="112.0">
          <tableCell term="72" selectedCell="false" maxCell="73">
            <number>21.7</number>
          </tableCell>
          <tableCell term="74" selectedCell="true" maxCell="75">
            <number>21.7</number>
          </tableCell>
        </tableRow>
        <tableRow max="200" value="15" selectedRow="false" maxRow="113.0">
          <tableCell term="76" selectedCell="false" maxCell="77">
            <number>14.5</number>
          </tableCell>
          <tableCell term="78" selectedCell="false" maxCell="79">
            <number>22.5</number>
          </tableCell>
        </tableRow>
        <tableRow max="300" value="20" selectedRow="false" maxRow="114.0">
          <tableCell term="80" selectedCell="false" maxCell="81">
            <number>14.6</number>
          </tableCell>
          <tableCell term="82" selectedCell="false" maxCell="83">
            <number>15.7</number>
          </tableCell>
        </tableRow>
      </callbackTable>
    </approved>
  </return>
</process>';

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable([Max],[Value],[SelectedRow],[MaxRow],[Term],[SelectedCell],[MaxCell],[Number])
SELECT
     tableRow.value('data(./@max)', 'varchar(10)')
    ,tableRow.value('data(./@value)', 'int')
    ,tableRow.value('data(./@selectedRow)', 'varchar(10)')
    ,tableRow.value('data(./@maxRow)', 'decimal(10,1)')
    ,tableCell.value('data(./@term)', 'int')
    ,tableCell.value('data(./@selectedCell)', 'varchar(10)')
    ,tableCell.value('data(./@maxCell)', 'int')
    ,tableCell.value('./number[1]', 'decimal(10,1)')
FROM @xml.nodes('//tableRow') AS tableRow(tableRow)
CROSS APPLY tableRow.nodes('//tableCell') AS tableCell(tableCell);
```